# Insert CSS in PHP if statement

Tags: php, css, if-statement

I am using PHP to determine if a user is on a mobile device or desktop browser. Right now I have the statement set to echo a "yes" or "no." Those are both functioning correctly. However, I want to add certain CSS code if the device is mobile and certain CSS code if it is not. Is this possible?

Here is an example:

```
$ismobile = check_user_agent('mobile');
if($ismobile) {
    <div id="slider1">
         Sample Text
        </div>

} else {
    <div id="slide2">
        Sample Text 2
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: just add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...." />` in the document head, using the same PHP if() structure.

Comment: `#slider1 { background-color: red; } #slide2 { background-color: blue; }`??

Comment: The best way to deal with this issue is to use css media query instead of a mobile detection (same website for every devices). However, you can create two separate css files, that you can load with a condition.
Otherwise, just add desktop + mobile css inside the same file it will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ismobile = check_user_agent('mobile');
if($ismobile) {
    ?><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css">
<?php
} else {
    ?><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css">
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just like you echo "yes" and "no", you can echo your CSS styles inside a HTML style tag, or, even better, load a CSS file (`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`).

Comment: I like this answer and I think we can work from here. But I actually want to display a different div if it is mobile or a different div if it is a desktop browser. I don't think you can put a div in a stylesheet. Can you?

Comment: I figured this out on my own somehow (who has any idea how!) Regardless, I just needed to end my PHP tags and begin them again before and after my CSS code. Everything works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a class on your body like `<body class="mobile">`
and then use css to target specifically the mobile or not

```
.mobile #mydiv {background:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this. I would first look into media queries because it is a bit of a neater solution and means you dont need to mix in php.

However the quick way would be

```
    <?php
    $ismobile = check_user_agent('mobile');
    if($ismobile) {?>
        <div id="slider1"> Sample Text</div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div id="slide2">Sample Text 2</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add two different style sheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo check_user_agent('mobile') ? 'mobile' : 'desktop'; ?>.css">
```

Or just add a class to the body tag:

```
<body class="<?php echo check_user_agent('mobile') ? 'mobile' : ''; ?> another-body-class">
```

But you really should be using [CSS Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) which bases appearance off of screen resolution not the User Agent screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ismobile = check_user_agent('mobile');
$style = $ismobile ? 'mobile' : 'notmobile';

echo '<div id="slider1" class='.$style.'>
   Sample Text
</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other replies work, I like to slimline code, so I'd stick it on 2 lines and be done with it.

```
$ismobile = check_user_agent('mobile') ? 'mobile' : 'main' ;
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $ismobile . '.css">';
```

The logic behind it is simple. You have 2 stylesheets, named main.css for the main template, while mobile.css is for the mobile layout.

With that in mind, $ismobile always returns true or false, ending in mobile.css or main.css, depending on return value.

As you will ALWAYS catch one of the 2 (true or false), you will always have a value for the included stylesheet.

The end result is that you have 2 stylesheets, rendering the need to have 2 divs, which duplicated the code at html level, since #slider can be defined with 2 separate sets of attributes in each, which means #slide2 isn't needed.